# How to read .rpt files in Java and save it as pdf

Tags: java, pdf, report, java-7, rpt

I have a .rpt file. I want to read it programatically in java and save it in pdf file.
I followed the solution
[multithread pdf conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438995/how-to-generate-pdf-documents-from-rpt-in-a-multi-threaded-approach)
My source code provided below

```
  final String rpt = "/Users/florapc/Desktop/Report/AcStatement.rpt";
  final String sFilePath = "/Users/florapc/Desktop/Report/";
  final String sFileName = "pdfreport";
  final Object[] data = new Object[1];
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      //  run();
      Engine eng = new Engine(Engine.EXPORT_PDF);
      eng.setReportFile(rpt); //rpt is the report name

      System.out.println(" After set connection");
      eng.setPrompt(data[i], 0);
      ReportProperties repprop = eng.getReportProperties();
      //  repprop.setPaperOrient(ReportProperties.DEFAULT_PAPER_ORIENTATION, ReportProperties.PAPER_FANFOLD_US);
      eng.execute();
      System.out.println(" After excecute");
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      try {
          String FileName = sFileName + "_" + i;
          File file = new File(sFilePath + FileName + ".pdf");
          if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
              file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
          }
          if (!file.exists()) {
              file.createNewFile();
          }
          fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
          for (int k = 1; k <= eng.getPageCount(); k++) {
              fos.write(eng.getPageData(k));
          }
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          if (fos != null) {
              try {
                  fos.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              fos = null;
          }
      }
  }
```

After running my code I am unable to read the .rpt file and my pdf file becomes empty.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get a solution using iTextPdf library.

```
 package com.fsl;
    import com.fsl.Main;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument;
    import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.IParameterField;
    import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Anchor;
    import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Chapter;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
    import com.itextpdf.text.List;
    import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Section;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

    public class iTextTest {

    private static String FILE = String.format("/Users/florapc/Desktop/Report/%s.pdf",getDateTimeString());
    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
            Font.BOLD);
    private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
            Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
    private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
            Font.BOLD);
    private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
            Font.BOLD);

    public static  String getDateTimeString()
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
       return dtf.format(now);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {


            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
            document.open();
    //            Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    //            addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
               // addMetaData(document);
               addTitlePage(document);
    
               // addContent(document);
                document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    // iText allows to add metadata to the PDF which can be viewed in your Adobe
    // Reader
    // under File -> Properties
    private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
        document.addTitle("My first PDF");
        document.addSubject("Using iText");
        document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
        document.addAuthor("Lars Vogel");
        document.addCreator("Lars Vogel");
    }

    private static void addTitlePage(Document document)
            throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
//        // We add one empty line
       addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        generatePDFReport(preface, 1);
//        // Lets write a big header
//        preface.add(new Paragraph("Title of the document", catFont));
//
//        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
//        // Will create: Report generated by: _name, _date
//        preface.add(new Paragraph(
//                "Report generated by: " + System.getProperty("user.name") + ", " + new Date(), //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
//                smallBold));
//        addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
//        preface.add(new Paragraph(
//                "This document describes something which is very important ",
//                smallBold));
//
//        addEmptyLine(preface, 8);

        //preface.add(new Paragraph(
                //"This document is a preliminary version and not subject to your license agreement or any other agreement with vogella.com ;-).",
              //  redFont));

        document.add(preface);
        // Start a new page
        document.newPage();
    }

    private static void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("First Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("First Chapter");

        // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
        Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 1", subFont);
        Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));

        subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 2", subFont);
        subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 1"));
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 2"));
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 3"));

        // add a list
        createList(subCatPart);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        addEmptyLine(paragraph, 5);
        subCatPart.add(paragraph);

        // add a table
        createTable(subCatPart);

        // now add all this to the document
        document.add(catPart);

        // Next section
        anchor = new Anchor("Second Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("Second Chapter");

        // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
        catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory", subFont);
        subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("This is a very important message"));

        // now add all this to the document
        document.add(catPart);

    }

    private static void createTable(Section subCatPart)
            throws BadElementException {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

        // t.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        // t.setPadding(4);
        // t.setSpacing(4);
        // t.setBorderWidth(1);

        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header 1"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header 2"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header 3"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);

        table.addCell("1.0");
        table.addCell("1.1");
        table.addCell("1.2");
        table.addCell("2.1");
        table.addCell("2.2");
        table.addCell("2.3");

        subCatPart.add(table);

    }

    private static void createList(Section subCatPart) {
        List list = new List(true, false, 10);
        list.add(new ListItem("First point"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Second point"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Third point"));
        subCatPart.add(list);
    }

    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
//        ReportClientDocument rcd = new ReportClientDocument();
//
//        String rptPath="/Users/florapc/Desktop/Report/AcStatement.rpt";
//
//        try {
//            rcd.open(rptPath, 0);
//        } catch (ReportSDKException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        System.out.println(rptPath);
//        java.util.List<IParameterField> fld = null;
//        try {
//            fld = rcd.getDataDefController().getDataDefinition().getParameterFields();
//        } catch (ReportSDKException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//
//        java.util.List<String> reportContent = new ArrayList<String>();
//        System.out.println(fld.size());
//        for (int i = 0; i < fld.size(); i++) {
//
//            System.out.println(fld.get(i).getDescription());
//            String res=fld.get(i).getDescription().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ");
//            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(res));
//
//
//        }
    }
    private static void generatePDFReport(Paragraph paragraph, int number)
    {
        ReportClientDocument rcd = new ReportClientDocument();

        String rptPath="/Users/florapc/Desktop/Report/AcStatement.rpt";

        try {
            rcd.open(rptPath, 0);
        } catch (ReportSDKException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(rptPath);
        java.util.List<IParameterField> fld = null;
        try {
            fld = rcd.getDataDefController().getDataDefinition().getParameterFields();
        } catch (ReportSDKException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        java.util.List<String> reportContent = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(fld.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < fld.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(fld.get(i).getDescription());
            String res=fld.get(i).getDescription().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ");
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(res));


        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will be helpfull to all .